# Knife tool creates others faces

Tags: modeling, mesh

The tool simply creates other vertices and edges to be the closest edge, if it is 3-sided it is cut, it generates 2 lines and if it is 3-sided it generates a line.

[image: Using knife normally]

[image: What?]

Comment: Hello :). This is correct behavior - in Blender, all holes must be connected by at least two edges. If not, Blender will add those edges for you.